# Systemd smb.service management

Tags: linux, samba, systemd

I have recently added some samba shares into the smb.conf file on RHEL 7.2 Following this, I restarted the samba service in systemctl. 
However this caused all the citrix service to disconnect and resulted in some stale sessions that are causing issues. 
It now looks like even after clearing the sessions the citrix boxes will need to be bounced.

The question here is: Could I have used

systemctl reload smb.service instead of systemctl restart smb.service ?

I can't find any list to state which services are supported by reload, and which have to be restarted. Does anyone know for sure about this?

Thanks 
Colin